# Quasar Intersection search and filter

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, quasar

I am trying to create a filter/search possibility for a [QIntersection](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/intersection#Basic) in Quasar.
Preferably in the same style as a [QTable](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/table#Grid-style), where it searches through an entire JSON.

My goal is to use a v-for loop over a JSON to create all intersection items, with a QSelect that gives the possibility for searching and filtering.

Anyone suggestions on how to approach this the best?

Comment: Just like you would do it without `QIntersection`. Create a computed field that you use for your `v-for` and within that computed filter based on `QSelect` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Matthias S thanks your suggestion works perfectly.